# how to call javascript function in <a4j:commandLink> before action takes place in jsf

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

actually i have a inputTextarea , and i want to get the value from it and append some values, before action takes place in BackingBean. how to achieve this! I tried but the a4j:commandLink  does not invoke action after calling javascript on onClick event.

i refers this reference
[action method is not called in <a4j:commandLink> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12093461/action-method-is-not-called-in-a4jcommandlink-tag)

[How can I execute Javascript before a JSF <h:commandLink> action is performed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73628/how-can-i-execute-javascript-before-a-jsf-hcommandlink-action-is-performed)

http://balusc.blogspot.in/2009/05/javajspjsf-and-javascript.html
Actually My code:

JavaScript in common file

```
 function call()
    {
        var test= document.getElementById('inputId').value;
      test="hai"; //some code

     document.getElementById('inputId').value=test;
return true;
    }

in jsf
<a4j:commandLink onclick="if (!call()) return false;"
    action="#{bean.createUser()}"
    execute="@form">
    <h:graphicImage style="border-style:none;" url="/images/create.jpg"
        height="10px" />
</a4j:commandLink>
```

Comment: can you just replace `execute="@form"` with `execute="@this, inputId"` in your code and try again?

Comment: ya ! i tried..but..i want to save complete form data to db..so i placed @form there.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a native html link and an `a4j:jsFunction` to achieve that.

```
<a href="#" onclick="appendFunctionHere(); jsFunctionToCallAction(); return false;">Click</a>

<a4j:jsFunction name="jsFunctionToCallAction" action="#{myManagedBean.myActionMethod}" ... />
```

Comment: i have tried this...

<a4j:commandLink onclick="if (!call()) return false;"
    action="#{bean.createUser()}"
    execute"@form">
    <h:graphicImage style="border-style:none;" url="/images/Save.jpg"
        height="10px" />
</a4j:commandLink>

but the action bean is not invoking

Comment: well, it doesn't seem to be related to my solution, right? :)

Comment: i am very thankful to you ...for your response..but...i need in this way.because i cant change the jsf tag. what shall i do..???

Comment: sure, no problem. but can i ask why you cannot change the jsf tag? maybe we can find a simple answer for that, too.

Comment: Due to the requirement by Software Architects..if i get simple solution without changing and affecting the design and tag... and i am new in it...and just getting into it..if i could get simple solution within time limited time period..it would be a..help